# Python AppIndicator menu freezes

Tags: python, pygtk, appindicator

I am trying to create an appindicator with one menu item displaying a variable status message.  This works for a while, but then the text of the menu item stops updating.  Here's a minimal non-working example that I've created in an attempt to isolate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading,time
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as AppIndicator

i = 0
def tinker_with_menu_item():
    global i
    while True:
        i = i + 1
        menu_item.get_child().set_text("We are now at " + str(i) + ".")
        menu_item.queue_draw()            ###
        while Gtk.events_pending():       ###
            print "events pending ..."    ###
            Gtk.main_iteration_do(True)   ###
        time.sleep(0.01)

menu_item = Gtk.MenuItem('')
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu.append(menu_item)
menu.show_all()
appindicator = AppIndicator.Indicator.new("my-app-indicator", Gtk.STOCK_INFO, AppIndicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
appindicator.set_menu(menu)
appindicator.set_status(AppIndicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
thread = threading.Thread(target=tinker_with_menu_item)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()       
Gtk.main()
```

Sometimes, the text in the menu item counts up into the high ten-thousands, sometimes it already stops in the early hundreds. 
Further details:

- I added the lines marked `###` after reading some proposed solutions in similar stackoverflow questions.  However, they don't resolve the issue.  The line "events pending ..." never appears in the terminal.
- Updating a panel *icon* in a similar way works flawlessly.  If I update both a menu item as above and the appindicator's panel icon, the icon keeps updating even after the menu item has frozen.
- I'm using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity desktop).

Any ideas?

Comment: What about adding a `thread.join()` after start?

Comment: Indeed, adding  `thread.join()` after `thread.start()` works in this minimal example -- "events pending ..." is now printed all the time, and the menu item keeps updating. But doesn't `thread.join()` have the side effect that Gtk.main() is never executed?  I’m not sure I can do without Gtk.main() in the actual appindicator application I have in mind.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: In the end, my script is supposed to: (1) show a dialog window offering to run various programs like backintime, unison ... consecutively, (2) execute these programs (using Popen), (3) translate the terminal output from these programs into a changing panel icon;  in addition, I'm trying to display the actual terminal output in a panel menu item.  Everything is working, except that after a while the menu freezes as described.

Comment: Have you looked at  this?  https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading

Comment: No.  Or rather:  Yes, now I have.  That was indeed the place to look.  I've now  "wrapped" the line `menu_item.get_child().set_text(...)` with `GLib.idle_add(...)` and deleted all the lines marked `###`, and now the menu seems to be updating fine.  If you post this an an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the final answer from Padraic Cunningham and the OP in the comments (it also helped me):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading, time
import gi
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as AppIndicator

i = 0
def tinker_with_menu_item():
    global i
    while True:
        i = i + 1
        def update_text():
          menu_item.get_child().set_text("We are now at " + str(i) + ".")
        GLib.idle_add(update_text)
        time.sleep(0.01)

menu_item = Gtk.MenuItem(label='')
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu.append(menu_item)
menu.show_all()
appindicator = AppIndicator.Indicator.new("my-app-indicator", Gtk.STOCK_INFO, AppIndicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
appindicator.set_menu(menu)
appindicator.set_status(AppIndicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
thread = threading.Thread(target=tinker_with_menu_item)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()       
Gtk.main()
```